# How can I create Translate storyboard animation programmatically UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

I would like to create dynamic Translate Y animations for my grids, but I can't find how to do it in UWP programmatically.

I have this code, but it says

WinRT information: Cannot resolve TargetProperty TranslateY on specified object.

I have tried to set property name to Y, but it says:

WinRT information: Cannot resolve TargetProperty Y on specified object.

Sample:

```
private void CreateStoryBoardAnimation(Grid myGrid)
{
    myGrid.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform();

    Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();

    DoubleAnimation translateYAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
    translateYAnimation.From = -500;
    translateYAnimation.To = 1;
    translateYAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));

    Storyboard.SetTarget(translateYAnimation, myGrid);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(translateYAnimation, "TranslateY");

    storyboard.Children.Add(translateYAnimation);

    storyboard.Begin();
}
```

I have also tried to use TranslateTransform class... But I don't get how could i use it.

Storyboard.SetTargetProperty only accepts a string in UWP.

I would like to move my grid on screen with animation. I know how to make a storyboard animation in blend, but that is not an option in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is totally true only use this line :

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(translateYAnimation, "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)");
```

instead of

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(translateYAnimation, "TranslateY");
```

That's it . Have a great day :)

Comment: SetTargetProperty does NOT accept Strings as parameters but only "PropertyPath"

Comment: @MatteoGariglio you're looking at the wrong api. UWP does have a SetTargetProperty(Timeline element, string path)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.storyboard.settargetproperty?view=winrt-19041

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to define animation in xaml and update all required parameters in code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="SlidingAnimatoin">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TranslateTransform"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y"
                             From="100"
                             To="0"
                             Duration="0:0:0.5">
            </DoubleAnimation>
        </Storyboard>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform x:Name="TranslateTransform"/>
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
</Grid>
```

In code you can access storyboard by its name `SlidingAnimatoin` and update any properties even in `DoubleAnimation`.